# How to get matplotlib osx rendering to work?

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I'm getting the following error:

> RuntimeError: Python is not installed as a framework. The Mac OS X backend will not be able to function correctly if Python is not installed as a framework. See the Python documentation for more information on installing Python as a framework on Mac OS X. Please either reinstall Python as a framework, or try one of the other backends. If you are using (Ana)Conda please install python.app and replace the use of 'python' with 'pythonw'. See 'Working with Matplotlib on OSX' in the Matplotlib FAQ for more information.

when trying to run:

```
%matplotlib osx
```

in a Jupyter notebook

I've installed `python.app` via `conda` as suggested. But how do I make the kernel to work with the `pythonw` instead of `python`?

I'm aware of related question on stackoverflow, none of them have answered this

Comment: Are you sure you have gone through ['Working with Matplotlib on OSX'](https://matplotlib.org/faq/osx_framework.html)? Especially where it says: *"This approach can be followed even if using Jupyter notebooks: you just need to setup a kernel with the suitable PYTHONHOME definition. The jupyter-virtualenv-osx script automates the creation of such a kernel."*

Comment: Yes, as a matter of fact I have tried that script and it resulted in a clusterf*ck of a kernel that restarts and crashes in an endless loop